# S3 notification when file is overwritten, or deleted

Tags: amazon-s3

since we store our log files on S3 and to meet PCI requirements we have to be notified when someone tampers with the log files.

How can I be notified every time a put request is placed that replaces an existing object, or when an existing object is delete. The alert should not fire if a new object is created unless it replaces an existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S3 does not currently provide <strike>deletion or</strike> overwrite-only notifications.  Deletion notifications [were added after the initial launch of the notification feature](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-delete-notifications-better-filters-bucket-metrics/) and can notify you when an object is deleted, but does not notify you when on object is implicitly deleted by overwrite.

However, S3 does have functionality to accomplish what you need, in a way that seems superior to what you are contemplating: object versioning and multi-factor authentication for deletion, both discussed here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html

With versioning enabled on the bucket, an overwrite of a file doesn't remove the old version of the file.  Instead, each version of the file has an opaque string, assigned by S3, identifying the Version ID.

If someone overwrites a file, you would then have two versions of the same file in the bucket -- the original one and the new one -- so you not only have evidence of tampering, you also have the original file, undisturbed.  Any object with more than one version in the bucket has, by definition, been overwritten at some point.

If you also enable Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) Delete, then none of the versions of any object can be removed without access to the hardware or virtual MFA device.

As an developer of AWS utilities, tools, and libraries (3rd party; I'm not affiliated with Amazon), I am highly impressed by Amazon's implementation of object versioning in S3, because it works in such a way that client utilities that are unaware of versioning or that versioning is enabled on the bucket should not be affected in any way.  This means you should be able to activate versioning on a bucket without changing anything in your existing code.  For example:

- fetching an object without an accompanying version id in the request simply fetches the newest version of the object
- objects in versioned buckets aren't really deleted unless you explicitly delete a particular version; however, you can still "delete an object," and get the expected response back.  Subsequently fetching the "deleted" object without specifying an accompanying version id still returns a 404 Not Found, as in the non-versioned environment, with the addition of an unobtrusive `x-amz-delete-marker:` header included in the response to indicate that the "latest version" of the object is in fact a [delete marker placeholder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeleteMarker.html).  The individual versions of the "deleted" object remain accessible to version-aware code, unless purged.
- other operations that are unrelated to versioning, which work on non-versioned buckets, continue to work the same way they did before versioning was enabled on the bucket.

But, again... with code that is version-aware, including the AWS console (two new buttons appear when you're looking at a versioned bucket -- you can choose to view it with a versioning-aware console view or versioning-unaware console view) you can iterate through the different versions of an object and fetch any version that has not been permanently removed... but preventing unauthorized removal of objects is the point of MFA delete.

Additionally, of course, there's [bucket logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html), which is typically only delayed by a few minutes from real-time and could be used to detect unusual activity... the history of which would be preserved by the bucket versioning.

Comment: Just a note so others don't misread this as I did: S3 notification(s) of the relevant (e.g. PUT, multipart upload) type(s) *are* generated when an object is overwritten. As noted by Michael, there just isn't an overwrite-*only* notification.

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't appear you can tell from the payload of the event notification that a new version was created. i.e. You have to make a "list versions" request to S3.

Comment: @spieden that is correct.  The notifications only tell you about the object/object version that was created.  You'd have to check the bucket listing or an external database (for example, I keep my S3 objects indexed in MariaDB or Aurora, depending on region, where I can search by metadata, dates, sizes, etags, etc.).