# Notifications when an S3 object is overwritten with versioning ON

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a way to configure an S3 bucket to enable notifications/alerts whenever another version of an object is created? I am using versioning to prevent overriding an existing object but I would like also to be able to detect such events.

With versioning, an overwrite will not actually delete the existing object but it well add another object to the same key but with a different version. I would like to configure the bucket to receive a notification only when an object is created on top of another object (again, since we have versioning).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [S3 notification when file is overwritten, or deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548422/s3-notification-when-file-is-overwritten-or-deleted)

Comment: You can probably create a notification on Put, but then you'll need some code to determine whether it was a new object or an overwrite.

Comment: Was this resolved?